# My marker don't show exact id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui-router

**OBJECT**

```
 var malls = [{

  id: 0,
  name: 'Leclerc',
  lastname: 'Paris,France',
  address:'Boulevard Rahal El Meskini Casablanca Maroc',

  ]

},

{
  /*Malls B*/
  id: 1,
  name: 'Carefour',
  lastname: 'Toulouse,France',
  address:'Angle Zaid Ou Hmad  Rue Sidi Belyout, Casablanca Maroc',  }, ];
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
 var address = "";//document.getElementById('address').value;
  var id_mall ="";
  var malls = Malls.all();
  for (var i = 0; i < malls.length; i++) {
     mall = malls[i];
     addMarker(mall);}




 function addMarker(address) {

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng
  }
id = mall.id;
  address = mall.address;
  console.debug(address);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              title: 'shopping center',
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              url:'#/tab/malls/'+id
      });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.location.href=marker.url;
    });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }

  });
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

}
```

I have 2 markers, and when I click on a marker , I receive :tab/malls/1 and the other the same thing  normally have to be /tab/malls/0 and  tab/malls/1 , 
I did not find the solution.

Please need help

Comment: Do both markers show up? Each with the corresponding information? Is it just the ID that is the same?

Comment: no any information !

Comment: i need help please...

Comment: Do any of the markers show up?

Comment: the markers showing, i'm talking about id

Answer (score 1):

Your object code appears malformed: there is an unmatched ] character on line 8. Try deleting this character and running it.